# Google sheet time difference calculation

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I want to calculate Total of time difference by creating a funtion in Google Sheet
The format of time Difference is : text(C7-B7,"hh:mm:ss")
[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct1jT.png)

How should I calculate the total of time difference.If I use Add ons it works well but I want to make a custom function which calculates the total of all the difference hours as soon as stop is clicked

Comment: See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sum, stay away from the text-conversion implied in the formula you shared. Instead try something like:

```
=MOD(C7-B7, 1)
```

and set the formatting of the column to 'duration' (if needed).
Then you should be able to sum the differences and obtain the total.

Hope that helps?

Comment: I want to add all the difference as eg Total Time :  0:00:18   which is calculated by addons with Time Tracker. I tried manually  using  =SUM(D2:D7) but it gives 0.

Comment: Can you share  (a copy of) your spreadsheet. That would be a great help in trying to solve this issue.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xo1aQ4NoyZt3LK4Kd01F9RlpXwKmYHpYzIFmxm8HHUs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please allow editing. Then we can work on this together.

Comment: Done ,You can access

Comment: As soon as I click stop in Add ons(Time Tracker ) I want total of time difference in h:mm:ss format